# Reformating the output of view in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my view which gives output as mentioned:

```
CREATE
  ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED
  DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW new_view AS
  SELECT 'pcount'    AS ind_type,
         SUM(pcount) AS Index_val
  FROM   temp
UNION
  SELECT 'ncount',
         SUM(ncount)
  FROM   temp
;
```

Result:

```
+----------+-----------+
| ind_type | Index_val |
+----------+-----------+
| pcount   |        76 |
| ncount   |       434 |
+----------+-----------+
```

Now I have created another key which takes `pcount` and `ncount` from another table using `MAX()`

```
CREATE
  ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED
  DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW view_name AS
  SELECT pcount,
         ncount
  FROM   temp
  WHERE  id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM temp)
;
```

gives result:

```
+--------+--------+
| pcount | ncount |
+--------+--------+
|     56 |     56 |
+--------+--------+
```

How this result can be seen as above one?

Result as per stephan's answer:

```
+----------+-----------+
| ind_type | Index_val |
+----------+-----------+
|        0 |         0 |
+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
CREATE VIEW test.t1 AS (
    SELECT 
        'pcount' AS type,
        `temp`.`pcount` AS value 
    FROM 
        `temp` 
    WHERE (
        `temp`.`id` = (
                SELECT 
                    MAX(`temp`.`id`) 
                FROM 
                    `temp`
        )
    )
    UNION 
    SELECT 
        'ncount' AS type,
        `temp`.`ncount` AS value 
    FROM 
        `temp` 
    WHERE (
        `temp`.`id` = (
                SELECT 
                    MAX(`temp`.`id`) 
                FROM 
                    `temp`
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks buddy! I dont want to do `sum` now. Table has single values only!

Comment: @user2129623 no worries , why do you need sum here ?

Comment: @user2129623 to pivot the data like you want, did you execute the query? isn't it in the format you need?

Comment: can you please compile it. I could not figure out!

Comment: `CREATE

    VIEW `test`.`t1` AS (SELECT `pcount` AS TYPE `temp`.`pcount` AS VALUE  FROM `temp` WHERE(`temp`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`temp`.`id`)             FROM                 `temp`    ))UNION SELECT    'ncount' AS TYPE    `temp`.`ncount` AS VALUE FROM `temp` WHERE (`temp`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`temp`.`id`) FROM `temp`))` updated

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`.t1 AS (SELECT pcount AS TYPE temp.pcount AS VALUE FROM temp WHERE(temp.id = (S' at line 1`

Comment: @user2129623 i posted the complete query pls try it now

Comment: still error : `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`temp`.`pcount` AS value 
    FROM 
        `temp` 
    WHERE (
        `temp`.`' at line 4
`

Comment: sorry about this, it was my fault i forgot the commas in the selection field, try now

Comment: Yes I did it, any ways result looks something different, see my main question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37518/discussion-between-stephan-and-user2129623)

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot the results of the query in your second example using a virtual table consisting of two rows (according to the number of columns you are unpivoting). Here's how it might look:

```
SELECT t.ind_type,
       CASE t.ind_type
         WHEN 'pcount' THEN v.pcount
         ELSE               v.ncount
       END AS Index_val
FROM   temp AS v
CROSS
JOIN   (
       SELECT 'pcount' AS ind_type
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'ncount'
       ) AS t
WHERE  v.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM temp)
```